# How to set edge color in nxviz Arcplot?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a DiGraph() in NetworkX and would like to set edge color for each edge in an  CircosPlot. I'm using the following syntax (this is just an example):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,color='r',weight=2)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='b',weight=4)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

edges = G.edges()
colors = [G[u][v]['color'] for u,v in edges]
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]

a = CircosPlot(G, figsize=(15,15), edge_color=colors)

a.draw()
plt.show()
```

This results in the following error:
**TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

Any ideas how to get the edge color working on CircosPlot? (Note that the same code with nx.draw instead of CircosPlot works)

Comment: Hey there Danny, I'm trying to reproduce your error, but I get an error.
Are you using the nxviz package and forgot to import it in your code? Or am I missing something? I managed to reproduce something similar by adding `import nxviz as nv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of adding a few more nodes to he graph so nodes in the `CircosPlot` are a bit smaller (big nodes make it harder to see the edges).

I also increased the edge weights so the color is easier to see.

```py
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_node(5)
G.add_node(6)
G.add_edge(1,2,color='r',weight=6)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='b',weight=6)
G.add_edge(3,1,color='b',weight=6)

a = nxv.CircosPlot(G, node_labels='gender',
                   edge_color='color', edge_width='weight')
a.draw()
```

[image]

You have to specify the attribute name for the graph properties instead of a list. The API is similar to the seaborn package.

Comment: Hey Rabeez, sorry for the ignorance, but, in a simlar comment as I made to the question, are you not using nxviz as well? With networkx, I get "AttributeError: module networkx has no attribute CircosPlot". 
With nxviz, I also get an error, but it is "KeyError: 'node_labels'"
Could you also clarify if this is a version issue? I've got networkx 2.6.3 and nxviz 0.7.4.